# Ansible render variable from set variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I want to use `jinja2's template` for generate configuration. But I'm stuck with this. I use `set` for create new variable, after that I need to use fallowing string as new variable for rendering. My sample code which show what I want to achieve:

**play.yml**

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
     x: a
     y: 1

  tasks:
    - name: templating
      template:
        src: test.j2
        dest: test.txt
      vars:
       a1b: 'OK - work'
```

$ **test.j2**

```
{% set host = x ~ y|string ~ 'b' %}
base: {{ host }}
expected: {{ a1b }}
```

After that I get:

```
base: a1b
expected: OK - work
```

But I expected:

```
base: OK - work
expected: OK - work
```

It's any way to say `Jinja` that she could render new string? Something like `| render` filter?

> Note: `vars` section is necessary, because finally I want to use
>   `vars_prompt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some death simple workaround, but if someone has 'native' answer it would be great.

So:
**play.yml**

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
     x: a
     y: 1
     a1b: 'super_variable'

  tasks:

    - name: templating
      template:
        src: test.j2
        dest: tmp.j2
```

**test.j2** I just add `{{` as string to template.

```
{% set o = '{{' ~ x ~ y|string ~ 'b' ~ '}}' %
base: {{ host }}
expected: {{ a1b }}
```